# C++ Passing class Object to function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference, functional-programming

I'm new to C++ programming.
Now I have the state class. I want to create neighboring states with this class, so I add the function getNeighboringStates() to my class. In this function I pass in "neighboring_states" to function set_neighboring_state(), this function change "neighboring_states"'s value.
In this function, I set a for loop to test. It print out "7 1 0 3 6 4 5 2 8", which is the value I want. But In the function getNeighboringStates(), I also set a for loop that has the same mission as in set_neighboring_state(), but the screen display "0 1 4716672 2686652 2686528 0 4716676 4519501 4716676".

I don't know what's wrong with my code. What do I need to do now?

```
int n; // The number of columns as well as rows of the board
int k; // The kind of heuristic function to use
int tilesCount; // The number of tiles, including the blank one
int statesCount; // The number of states generated

int* m_initTiles;
int* m_goalTiles;
int tmpTile;


const int UP = 0;
const int DOWN = 1;
const int RIGHT = 2;
const int LEFT = 3;
int* direction;

class State {
public:


    State(){}

    int getBlankTilePosition() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {

            if (stateTiles[i] == 0)
                return i;

        }
    }

    void set_neighboring_state(State* neighboring_state, int direction) {
        int blankPosition = getBlankTilePosition();
        int neighbor_tiles[n * n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {
            neighbor_tiles[i] = getStateTiles()[i];
        }

        switch(direction) {
        case UP:
            if (blankPosition/n < 1) return;
            else {
                swap(neighbor_tiles[blankPosition], neighbor_tiles[blankPosition - n]);
                neighboring_state->set_tiles(neighbor_tiles);

                 // This for loop print out "7 1 0 3 6 4 5 2 8"
                 for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++)
                     cout << neighboring_state.getStateTiles()[i] << " "; cout << endl;
            }
            break;
        case DOWN:
            if (blankPosition/n == n - 1) return;
            else {
                swap(neighbor_tiles[blankPosition], neighbor_tiles[blankPosition + n]);
                neighboring_state->set_tiles(neighbor_tiles);
            }
            break;
        case LEFT:
            if (blankPosition % n == 0) return;
            else {
                swap(neighbor_tiles[blankPosition], neighbor_tiles[blankPosition - 1]);
                neighboring_state->set_tiles(neighbor_tiles);
            }
            break;
        default:
            if ((blankPosition + 1) % n == 0) return;
            else {
                swap(neighbor_tiles[blankPosition], neighbor_tiles[blankPosition + 1]);
                neighboring_state->set_tiles(neighbor_tiles);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    /*
    The maximum number of neighboring state that can be created is 4.
    This function return the neighboring states of a certain state.
    The first state represents for the "left" neighbor, the second,
    the third and the fourth represent the "right", "up, and "down"
    neighbor, respectively.
    */
    State* getNeighboringStates() {
        State* neighboring_states;
        neighboring_states = new State[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            set_neighboring_state(&neighboring_states[i], direction[i]);

        // This print out "0 1 4716672 2686652 2686528 0 4716676 4519501 4716676"
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++)
            cout << neighboring_states[0].getStateTiles()[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;

        return neighboring_states;
    }



    State(int* pStateTiles) {
        stateTiles = pStateTiles;
    }

    void set_tiles(int* tiles) {
        stateTiles = tiles;
    }

    int* getStateTiles() {
        return stateTiles;
    }

private:
    int* stateTiles;

};
void input(const char* fileName) {
ifstream fin;
fin.open(fileName);

// read n, k from file
fin >> n >> k;

// allocate m_initTiles and m_goalTiles memory
m_initTiles = new int[n * n];
m_goalTiles = new int[n * n];


for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++)
    fin >> m_initTiles[i];
for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++)
    fin >> m_goalTiles[i];

for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++)
    cout << m_initTiles[i] << " ";
cout << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++)
    cout << m_goalTiles[i] << " ";
cout << endl;

fin.close();

}

void initDirection() {
direction = new int[4];
direction[0] = UP;
direction[1] = DOWN;
direction[2] = RIGHT;
direction[3] = LEFT;
}

int main() {

input("nPuzzle.inp");
initDirection();
State init_state (m_initTiles);
State goal_state (m_goalTiles);

State* init_neighbor = init_state.getNeighboringStates();
// int* state_tile = init_neighbor[0].getStateTiles();
// for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++)
//  cout << state_tile[i] << " ";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step through with a decent debugger before asking.

Comment: `neighbor_tiles` is a local variable. You're storing pointers to its first element. Those become invalid when the function returns. Use `std::vector` if possible.

Comment: I just tried to make the post to be as detailed as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int blankPosition = getBlankTilePosition();
int neighbor_tiles[n * n];
```

Remove `int neighbor_tiles[n * n];` line from above code segment and make it global available to all function , so declare it as data of a class not for function i.e. `add int neighbor_tiles[n * n]; to class  as an data type .`

Comment: If you made a modification to their code, it would be helpful to the OP if you trimmed the code down to specifically what you changed, and why it needed to be changed (i.e. what was wrong with the way they had it).

Comment: @TheDarkKnight suggestion:Don't use global variable too much .You should use global variable as less as possible.